# How to create this rhombus shape

Tags: shaders, procedural

Can someone teach me how to create this rhombus shape procedurally (not geometry nodes) or link a greate resource so I can learn it from? [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any way of generating rectangular cells with distance-from-edge would do. Then you can rotate the texture, and scale after rotation. (That means the *inverse* of that transform on the space the texture is measured in.) Here, being lazy, and using a zero-random 2D *Voronoi*'s 'Distance From Edge'..

[image]

- Using *Float Curve* to shape the height profile
- Cheating, by shading the grooves with a darker tint. This may not be needed in different lighting conditions, or if using displacement rather than *Bump*, as in this example.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice - float curve - I never would of thought - my method instead was to pull my hair out trying to find the right grayscale balance that both brought out the grooves in a somewhat ill-defined manner, whilst nor simultaneously destroying the overall shape of the "diamond peaks" - all without visual nodes in the shader graph - how is it blender doesn't have this feature yet?

Comment: Hi @ChristopherBennett !  You used to have to use _RGB Curves_  to do that sort of thing.. Haven't I  _seen_ visual nodes, somewhere? Was that an Add-On, or a branch, or have i just gone doolally? I've just got used to shift-clicking bits of my tree..  it would be nice, though...

Comment: You've probably _seen_ it lots of places - Unity, Unreal, Substance Designer, even obscure engines like Godot do have, and have had, a visual graph for a many years now. There probably is some hard to find, paid addon that might create something of that nature, but I think given how far blender has come, it deserves to have it come stock. It's in my "wish bag" of things I wish blender had. ;)

Comment: Found the addon - https://blendermarket.com/products/node-preview?ref=236

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Ahh! That's the one. I saw it in its free-preview days.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this - it's just a couple of *Wave Textures*, tilted at a 20 degree angle and mixed together. I used the original textures for the mix as well as adding some "highlights" with the color-ramped sections to make the "grooves" more defined - the "dark" end of the color-ramps are not black, but a lighter grey (not sure that's clear in the photo.) At the end, I added some "Grunge" from a *Noise Texture* to make the surface more bumpy:

[image: Waves]